# java.io.IOException Error in Android studio when using the Lottie files

Tags: android, android-studio, lottie

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mashitha.smartwaterbottle"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'

    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

    implementation 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'

    //Google play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev328-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

when I add the "implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'", I'm getting this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Pavan\AndroidStudioProjects\Others Projects\And_Stu_app\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Pavan.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\bfd8b5be8898d98e8c2045ba6c6ace43\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

What is the reason for that?

Comment: implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:1.5.1' it's okay

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `supportLibrary` versions. It's probably due to a conflict in the versions. Either you in your code or Lottie's library is using a different `supportLibrary` version.

Interim fix can be to change the version to be same on both ends, or you could use `exclude` function of Gradle. for example -

```
implementation ('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'){
    exclude group: ‘com.android.support’, module: ‘support-v4’
    exclude group: ‘com.android.support’, module: ‘appcompat-v7’
    exclude group: ‘com.android.support’, module: ‘recyclerview-v7’
    exclude group: ‘com.android.support’, module: ‘design’
}
```

OR you could declare a Gradle configuration to exclude all support dependencies from 3rd party libraries, by adding this in your build.gradle -

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: ‘appcompat-v7’
    all*.exclude module: ‘support-v4’
}
```